# Why chrome.tabs.sendmessage doesn't accept the parameter of message?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I want to send the selected text value to my content script from the background script.
Here is the code I use:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({ 
  id: "TranslationFetcher",
  title: "Translate this word",
  contexts: ["selection"]
});


chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: info.selectionText}, {type: "getTranslation"});
  });
});
```

However, when I run the above code without the message parameter, the expected request is being passed to the content script.

How to resolve this error? and how to send the selected text to the content script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my bad I separate the message object. I figured it out. The answer is:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "getTranslation", message: info.selectionText});
  });
});
```

Comment: Further optimization: remove chrome.tabs.query and use the already provided parameter `tab.id`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But how it makes a difference? also, I want to get the message on a modal, how to get that?